# How can I access a swing component added to a JPanel that has not been declared?

Tags: java, swing

If I add a component (say a JLabel) to a JPanel without declaring it, is there a way I can access the JLabel after its instantiation?  I'm trying to set the alignment of the component but can't access the setAlignmentX() method even through getComponent().

```
testPanel.add(new JLabel("test label"));
testPanel.getComponent(0).setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

I've tried getComponent() but the setAlignmentX() method cannot be resolved, leading me to believe that the getComponent() method isn't returning the JLabel correctly, possibly because I never formally declared it.  I don't have any other components added to the JPanel.  I know I could always declare the JLabel prior to adding it to the JPanel, but I'd rather just add the `new JLabel("test label")` rather than declaring one prior to adding it.

Comment: Do you know it will always be a `JLabel` at that position/index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be considered best practice to declare the `JLabel` first as you've mentioned, but to answer your question...

The method `getComponent(int)` returns a `java.awt.Component`, not a `JComponent` (nor `JLabel`). `Component` has no such method `setAlignmentX` (it only has a getter).

Supposing you're sure the component you're getting is a `JLabel`, you'd have to cast it:

```
((JLabel)testPanel.getComponent(0)).setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

You might see that universalizing this necessary cast everywhere would be less maintainable than just declaring the `JLabel` first.

Comment: I agree with @Zircon.  I would also declare the JLabel. If you want to have more readable code (and have multiple JLabel to add) could create a addAlignedJLabel(String title) methode that does the declaration , the alignment and the adding to the panel.

Comment: Makes sense about the casting, I completely spaced the fact that it would return a component and not a JLabel.  I'll probably end up going the addAlignedJLabel route just for the sake of readability.